# What is this notation ($Z_3[x]_{x^2+1}$)? What are the elements of this?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, notation

I am auditing a Number Theory course. One of the question involves the "9 elements of $Z_3[x]_{x^2+1}$". I'm not familiar with this notation (and I can't seem to find it anywhere). What are the 9 elements of this, for lack of a better word, *thing* (ring?), and how are they found?

Comment: Do you mean the quotient ring of polynomials over integers modulo $3$  by the ideal $(x^2+1)$?  That's usually written $\mathbb Z_3[x]/(x^2+1)$ or more properly $\mathbb Z/(3\mathbb Z)[x]/(x^2+1)$.  Elements are $a+bx$ where $a,b\in\mathbb Z_3$

Comment: Aha. What's with the "$x^2+1$" bit?

Comment: It *could* be a localization, depending on context. Some authors use $R_f$ to denote the ring $R$ localized at the multiplicative subset $\{f^n\mid n\gt 0\}$ (equivalently, $R[\frac{1}{f}]$).

Comment: If your professor uses "weird" notation, they're the person to ask.

Comment: If you mean $\Bbb Z$ instead of $Z$, please use `\mathbb Z`, `\Bbb Z`, `\mathbb{Z}`, `\Bbb{Z}`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In standard notation, it should be $(\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z)[x]/(x^2 + 1)$, i.e. the polynomial ring over the field with $3$ elements, quotiented by the ideal generated by the polynomial $x^2 + 1$.

It is thus the unique (up to isomorphism) quadratic extension of $\Bbb F_3$, hence has $9$ elements.

These elements can be represented by $\{a + bx: a, b \in\{0, 1, -1\}\}$.

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) has more details.